# How To Get Angular To Work With An External SDK: (e.g., Update DOM After SDK Async Calls)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a client-side javascript SDK.  It makes requests to an external API easy.

But, when using it in Angular, I have to include $scope.apply() like this to get the DOM to update.

```
SDK.getUser(function(response) {
            // Have to call $scope.$apply since SDK call is asynchronous and therefore updates outside of the AngularJS digest cycle
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $rootScope.user = response.user;
            });
    }, function(error) {
            console.log('Error Fetching User From SDK: ', error);
    });
```

How can I modify the SDK so that $scope.apply() does not have to be written by developers using the SDK after its async calls complete?

Could I pass the $scope into the SDK and do the apply internally?

Comment: Instead of doing that you could wrap it in an angular service and use `$q` promises which will make sure digest cycle gets invoked, without you having to manually do it.

Comment: Since you going out of angular scope you would require to do an apply. You need to define an angular module or a directive to write the SDK. To avoid $apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I modify the SDK so that $scope.apply() does not have to be written by developers using the SDK after its async calls complete?

A better way to handle it would be to create an angular service wrapper over the SDK service so that you do not need to worry about manually invoking the digest cycle since angular will invoke the cycle once a promise is fulfilled and for each callback in the promise chain.

```
app.service('SDKWrapperService', ['$q',function($q){
  this.getUser = function() {
     var def = $q.defer();
     SDK.getUser(function(response) {
        def.resolve(response);
     },function(error) {
         def.reject('Error Fetching User From SDK: ', error);
    });
     return def.promise;
  }
}]);
```

And use it as something like this:-

```
app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope','SDKWrapperService', function($scope, SDKWrapperSvc){
      SDKWrapperSvc.getUser().then(function(data){
         $scope.user = data.user;
      })
 });
```

> Could I pass the $scope into the SDK and do the apply internally?

I would probably not do that since your *client-side javascript SDK (non-angular)*  will have to know about what is called a `$scope` and it actually will get more tightly coupled with an angular implementation.

If there is not too much of business logic involved, you could even have an angular version of your service utilizing [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) in your bundle for angular developers to use.